# Velocity of light and Reference of frames

Tags: reference-frames, speed-of-light

So, I recently came through a question regarding velocity of light, which goes like this

Choose the correct one

1. Velocity of light is constant in all media
2. Velocity of light in vacuum is maximum
3. Velocity of light is same in all reference frames
4. Laws of nature have identical form in all reference frames

**Now the correct answers are 2 and 4, but I am having difficulties in understanding 3 and 4 option (as 1 and 2 are obvious) because third option is the second postulate of our entire physics right, and i have no clue for the fourth one.**

Comment: Is this the actual statement of the question, or are you paraphrasing it? Because if this is a word-for-word quote of the question, then in my opinion it's phrased ambiguously and I would argue that whoever told you that choices 2 and 4 are correct is wrong. For 2, it really depends on what definition you're using for velocity-- phase velocity can be greater than $c$. Option 4 is just straight up incorrect-- it's only true for inertial frames.

Comment: how can anything go greater than c

Comment: In the context of special relativity, 3 is true for *inertial* reference frames only. In non-inertial reference frames (such as rotating frames or accelerating frames) it is not true.

Comment: @AugustaASAKA The problem is that "velocity" is an ambiguous phrase when you're talking about waves. It is true that the rate of information transfer cannot exceed $c$ in a vacuum, but there are other notions of velocity for waves that *can* exceed $c$ in some cases-- most prominently, the group velocity and phase velocity. But this isn't actually a problem, because these velocities need not represent the rate of information transfer (although they can in some cases). Don't sweat the details too much though-- my point is just that the question is worded ambiguously.